# Como chamar o valor de uma Subquery dentro de uma outra Subquery sendo que elas estão na mesma View

Tags: mysql

Tenho uma View com várias Subqueries, uma delas deverá ser utilizada para gerar uma outra Subquery dentro da própria View porém estou recebendo erro, exemplo:

```
(SELECT COUNT(0)
   FROM `LICENCAS`
  WHERE (`LICENCAS`.`FK_PEDIDO` = `A`.`FK_PEDIDO`) AND Dia_Corrido_Assinatura > `LICENCAS`.`CICLO`) AS `DownloadCount`,
(SELECT CEILING((TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, `A.``ASSINATURA_DATA_INICIO`, NOW()) / 86400))) AS `Dia_Corrido_Assinatura`,
FROM `N_ASSINATURAS` `A`
```

Estou tendo problema na Subquery `DownloadCount` pois dentro dela eu chamo o valor da Subquery `Dia_Corrido_Assinatura` porém eu recebo a mensagem:

> Error Code: 1247. Reference 'Dia_Corrido_Assinatura' not supported (forward reference in item list)

Eu até entendo que como é uma Subquery, ela talvez possa nem ter sido gerada para ser chamada, existem alguma opção em cima disso?

EDIT: já tentei mudar de ordem colocando a sub 'Dia_Corrido_Assinatura' primeiro, mas continuo com o mesmo erro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voce pode usar seu subselect dias_ocorridos no from. 
Como por exemplo:

```
SELECT 
--esse é seu subselect download
(SELECT COUNT(0)
   FROM `LICENCAS`
  WHERE (`LICENCAS`.`FK_PEDIDO` = `A`.`FK_PEDIDO`) AND tab.dias_ocorridos > `LICENCAS`.`CICLO`) AS `DownloadCount`
  tab.dias_ocorridos
FROM (SELECT referencia_id, 10 dias_ocorridos FROM N_ASSINATURAS) tab, N_ASSINATURAS
WHERE
N_ASSINATURAS.referencia_id = tab.referencia_id
```

Ou fazer uma função que retorne esse valor, ou uma outra view separada.
Voce não pode colunas criadas dentro da mesma clausula select. Tipo isso:

```
 select 1 um,
           2 dois,
           um+dois as soma
    from dual
```

Não funciona

Comment: Eu vou dar certo pois a sua ideia de criar uma view separada funcionou ! Obrigado.

Comment: Opa, que bom que deu certo